# PLSQL Trigger may be causing INSERT INTO to fail silently?

Tags: oracle, triggers, plsql

I have a table which I am trying to do an insert/update on depending on the values I am given. But the insert is not working for this particular table, yet it works for the previous tables which the script has run on.

To test this problem, I put in a few anonymous blocks into oracle's sqldeveloper which inserts or updates depending on whether a key is present. Updates seem to work fine, but when it comes to inserting a new row, nothing is inserted.

If I had this table:

```
COFFEE_ID       TEA_ID        NAME      
    11             100        combo 1
    12             101        combo 2
    13             102        combo 3
```

Doing this will not insert anything and will instead move on to the next anonymous block:

```
   begin
      insert into COFFEE_TEA(COFFEE_ID, TEA_ID, NAME) values (14, 103, 'combo 4');
   exception when dup_val_on_index then 
      update ....
   end;

    ....
```

I suspect it has something to do with the trigger on this table. It is a `BEFORE EACH ROW` trigger type, and it would do an insert data into some other table. There is no exception handling in the trigger, so I'm guessing it must fail but not report it (doesn't show up in sqldeveloper when I run the script).

My two questions would be,

When the trigger runs, what happens if the ID it's trying to insert to the other table already exists? Looks like it silently fails?

How best should I fix this? I am unsure if I can change the trigger code itself, but would it be possible to catch the error inside my anonymous block (assuming that it's actually the trigger that's causing the problem). If so, how would I know what exception to catch if it fails silently?

---

I removed the exception in sqldeveloper and it tells me that a unique constraint was violated. Namely that the data being inserted into the other table through the trigger is the cause.

Answer (score 3):

Your additional information tells us that your trigger is hurling ORA-00001, a unique key violation.  This is the error which the DUP_VAL_ON_INDEX exception handles.  So it seems like your exception handler which is supposed to be dealing with key violations on COFFEE_TEA is also swallowing the exceptions from your trigger.  Messy.

There are two possible solutions.  One is to put decent error handling in the trigger code.  The other is to use MERGE for your data loading routine.

I always prefer MERGE as a mechanism for performing upserts, because I don't like using exceptions to handle legitimate expected states.  [Find out more](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_9016.htm#i2081218).

Ideally you should do both.  Triggers are supposed to be self-contained code: imposing unhandled exceptions on routines which interact with their tables breaks the enscapsulation.

Answer (score 0):

A trigger will not modify the DML process on a table. Remove the exception block, the insert will either succeed or fail with an error if `COFFEE_TEA` is a table.

In other words, the following script will never output 0 if `COFFEE_TEA` is a table:

```
BEGIN
   INSERT INTO coffee_tea(COFFEE_ID, TEA_ID, NAME) values (14, 103, 'combo 4');
   dbms_output.put_line(sql%rowcount);
END;
```

Comment: Thanks, I removed the exception in sqldeveloper and it tells me that a unique constraint was violated.. namely that the data being inserted into the other table through the trigger is the cause. I supposed I could now catch that exception and perform according. Is there a better way?

Comment: @user1636922  Probably Merge statement could be other better way for you.